# Any drag and drop plugin for ionic3 and angular 5?

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

i tried many plugin in like :

- ng2-drag-drop
- ng-drag-drop
- ng2-dnd
- ngx-drag-drop
- angular4-drag-drop.

no one work for my ionic project any one can help me

- ionic cli version : 4.0.2
- ionic framework : 3.9.2
- angular: 5.0.0
- cordova cli : 7.1.0
- cordova platform android : 6.3.0